# ¿porque al extraer texto de una web con selenium, en python 3, me da un error de encode?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, scraping, unicode

Estoy realizando mi primera app con python, la idea de esta es extraer mensajes de la plataforma Twitch, para luego guardarlos en un .txt, utilizando selenium.
Cuando extraigo el texto me sale el error

> "UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character
> '\U0001f539' in position 2502: character maps to ",
> el código varia ya que no siempre no es el mismo carácter (algunos
> caracteres que me generaron el error son , , , etc)

Yo he leído que personas intentaban imprimirlo como str y se solucionaba, intente codificarlo con el encode y directamente escribit en el .txt con el codificado utf-8 por si el problema estaba cuando lo pasaba al archivo, pero nada funciona

Desde ya muchas gracias

garro

el código:

```
#busca la categoría con todos los mensajes (en toda la pagina)
mss= driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath_mss)
while x<=20:
for ms in mss:
#extraigo el texto de todo el codigo html (el comentario limpio)
    
    chat= ms.find_element_by_xpath(xpath_mss).text

    sd= ms.find_element_by_xpath(xpath_sd).text

#crea un  archivo con el chat
archivo=open("chat.txt","w", encoding="utf-8")
with open("chat.txt", "a") as f:
    f.write(str(chat))
archivo.close()

final_file = open("codes.txt", "w")
final_file.close() 
x+=1
time.sleep(20)
```

> Nota: a veces me salta un error similar pero lo que cambia es que
> directamente no reconoce el carácter y en vez de el code (U0001f539)
> me da la posición del carácter, por ejemplo: in position 3060-3064

Comment: ¿Si estableces el encoding al abrir `f` funciona? También `archivo` parece innecesaria.

Comment: @HernánAlarcón si cuando abro f no hay ninguna problema y crea el archivo de texto con los mensajes e incluso los extrae pero cuando aparecen esos emojis que mostré anteriormente me da error